# Oracle APEX Table/Viewer Owner dropdown

Tags: oracle, schema, oracle-apex

How do I edit which schemas appear in the dropdown menu for choosing a table owner for a new table, form, etc? I have already added the schemas I want in the APEX Internal. When creating a new application I see all my schemas as options but not in this dropdown for other applications in the same workspace. Also I am seeing schema options which are not assigned to this workspace. Where does this list come from?
[image]

Comment: I'd say exactly where you mentioned - connected as ADMIN user into INTERNAL workspace, then you "manage" that particular wokspace and add another schemas to it.

Comment: I have done this. They DO NOT show up in this particular drop down.  And schemas I have NOT added to the workspace DO show up in this drop down.

Comment: That's strange. Do you, by any chance, use two (or more) Apex' on different databases? Maybe - as ADMIN - you added schemas in one database but - as a developer - you use Apex on another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that list is the result of a select like this one

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  owner
  FROM
  all_tables
  WHERE owner NOT IN (<any of the internal oracle schemas like sys, system, ctxsys, etc>)
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT
  owner
  FROM
  all_views
  WHERE owner NOT IN (<any of the internal oracle schemas like sys, system, ctxsys, etc>)
;
```

This select is run as the database user who owns the application.
To test this: Suppose application is owned by SCOTT and schema HR exists but is not in the dropdown. Grant select on a table in the HR schema to SCOTT. Observe that HR now appears in the dropdown.

From an application perpective this makes sense - this select shows you schemas that have objects that the current schema has access to. What is the use of displaying a schema if there isn't any table in it you can select ?

Comment: Thank you! I actually figured this out late last night and was coming back here to post the solution. Strange that I could not find any info online about how this functionality works. Everyone just kept telling me to assign the schema to the workspace. Thanks for your help.